# Shouldn't git reset --hard 2ef82 get all my files like they were?

Tags: git

Shouldn't all the files in the committed, staging and working area be rewound to that commit? It's not working for me.

My intention was to commit, play around with my Rails project, then go back to that commit, but it didn't work...

MY GIT LOG:

```
Brians-MacBook-Air:social brianspinos777$ git log
commit f3671f19229482af889f561a44f9cf8708c6285b
Author: brian spinos <brianspinos777@hotmail.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 6 18:07:11 2012 -0500

    before dummie scaffold brian

commit 48c9df97919c7a67507197fea7d615c22d748f8d
Author: brian spinos <brianspinos777@hotmail.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 6 17:27:18 2012 -0500

    added a home page

commit bccb86c500b3519aeded25e42cf0359a17fa30e2
Author: brian spinos <brianspinos777@hotmail.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 6 17:08:37 2012 -0500

    commented the attr stuff in the model

commit e6c446fbf0e921691ea117b2054456aed2c9ea29
Author: brian spinos <brianspinos777@hotmail.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 6 15:57:13 2012 -0500

    migration success

commit de530a52e5191e288d185033d9df989112e4a2c4
Author: brian spinos <brianspinos777@hotmail.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 6 15:43:08 2012 -0500

    before rake db migrate
Brians-MacBook-Air:social brianspinos777$
```

Comment: Depends, did you happen to add any untracked files/directories?

Comment: yes, I did a "git add ." and "git commit -m "before mistakes""

Comment: No, I meant were there any untracked files as a result of the changes?  Also, what is the final result after you try the `git reset --hard`?

Comment: yes, there are untracked files. when I did the "git reset --hard" with the SHA number, it didnt affect my working area...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you want to checkout that hash

```
git checkout 2ef82
```

Comment: and what if its not a branch ?

Comment: You can checkout commits on the branch you are currently on by checking out the hash of the commit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849265/do-you-need-to-create-a-branch-to-check-out-a-specific-git-revision

Comment: I did a "git checkout f3671f19229482af889f5" but the files on my working area are the same, I want to rewind to how it was on that commit..

Comment: James, I put it with my question, on the top of the page.

Comment: The files will change contents if they were tracked back then, otherwise the new files will remain. You should be able to clean the directory with git clean -d -x -n

Comment: but there is one file remaining... look at this:                          Would not remove app/views/brians/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20726/discussion-between-james-mcdonnell-and-brian-joseph-spinos)